# Relation definition problem

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have this problem which I can't figure out the first part of:

> Let $A=\{2,3,4,8,9,12\}$, and let the relation $R$ on $A$ be defined by $aRb$ if and only if $(a\mid b\wedge a\ne b)$.

I believe that the part $b\wedge a \ne b$ means that you cannot have a relation of the type $(b,b)$, or another way to say it is that the relation cannot be reflexive, but I am really not sure.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You’re misreading the expression: it’s to be understood as $(a\mid b)\land(a\ne b)$, i.e., $a$ is a divisor of $b$, and $a$ is not equal to $b$.

Comment: Ahh, that would be it. It makes much more sense than what I was thinking of. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the relation rules out any pair of the form $( a,a)$.

It means that the relaton is irreflexive.

But note that ruling out all pairs of this form , though a sufficient condition for R to be non-reflexive, is not necessary. Ruling out all such pairs is necessary for a relation to be irreflexive.

***The absence of only one possible pair of this form is already a sufficient condition for R not to be reflexive***.

I mean that if your relation contained $( 2,2 )$ , $( 3,3 )$ , $( 4,4 )$ , 
$( 8,8 )$ , $(9 ,9  )$  ***but not the pair***$( 12, 12)$ , it would already be non- reflexive.